# iphone detect delegate event

Tags: iphone, events, delegates

I have developed one application in which i have to detect whether user has tapped home button or  whether call comes or whether lock (sleep/awake)button is pressed .
i read this http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/07/understanding-ios-4-backgrounding-and-delegate-messaging/
and according to it whether call comes or home button pressed or lock button pressed same event fired i have to detect seperately them. i have to apply one code which only fires when call comes not home or lock button is pressed

Comment: So which delegate methods have you used and which one gets called?  Show some more information so people might have a hope of helping you.

Comment: i used - (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {} and it fired when call comes or lock button pressed or home button is pressed

Comment: Which is absolutely correct and matches the details in the page you linked to.  Same goes for if you read the Apple docs on this subject.  As far as your app is concerned, it was interrupted for something and is no longer the active application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app cannot detect the difference between an incoming call or another interruption.